# Ajax Javascript PHP - Clicking too fast ruins numbers

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am building a shopping cart using Ajax, Javascript and PHP/MySQL. On the main shopping cart page, a user can click an image link to Add 1 or Remove 1 from each of their item selections. The Ajax uses a PHP script to Add 1 or Remove 1 to/from the amount for that item in the database and the javascript does the same for the shopping cart page. The problem I am having is that when I click too fast on either of these image links the values that exist in my database vs the values that exist on screen do not match up anymore. I thought this would be a fairly easy issue to fix, but I cannot seem to get it right. I've tried using usleep() in the PHP script, setTimeout() in the javascript, and I've tried setting a cookie (value = 1 when the update process starts, value = 0 when it finishes) and only allowing the process to run if value != 1, but none of this has solved my problem. The code is below.

cart.php

```
<a onClick='itemAddOne($item[id])' class='item_add'><img src='images/cart-add.jpg' alt='' onClick=this.src='images/cart-add_click.jpg' onMouseOut=this.src='images/cart-add.jpg'></img></a>
```

cart.js

```
var xmlhttp;
var sub_v;
var sub_v2;
var add_tot;
var element
var item_add;
var resp;
var prov;
var taxrate;
var finish;

function itemAddOne(itemID) {
    if (window.finish != 1) {
        finish = 1;
        document.cookie = "finish=1; path=/";
        xmlhttp.open("POST","add.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    add_tot = resp.substr(3);
                    prov = resp.substr(0,2);
                    if (prov == 'BC') {
                        taxrate = .12;
                    } else if (prov == 'AB') {
                        taxrate = .05;
                    } else if (prov == 'SK') {
                        taxrate = .05;
                    } else if (prov == 'MB') {
                        taxrate = .05;
                    } else if (prov == 'ON') {
                        taxrate = .13;
                    } else if (prov == 'QC') {
                        taxrate = .05;
                    } else if (prov == 'NL') {
                        taxrate = .13;
                    } else if (prov == 'NS') {
                        taxrate = .15;
                    } else if (prov == 'NB') {
                        taxrate = .13;
                    } else if (prov == 'PE') {
                        taxrate = .05;
                    } else if (prov == 'NT') {
                        taxrate = .05;
                    } else if (prov == 'NU') {
                        taxrate = .05;
                    } else if (prov == 'YT') {
                        taxrate = .05;
                    }
                    element = "item_quantity" + itemID;
                    item_add = document.getElementById(element);
                    tax_v = document.getElementById('tax');
                    tot_v = document.getElementById('tot');
                    sub_v = document.getElementById('subt');
                    item_add.value = Number(item_add.value) + 1;
                    sub_v.value = (Number(sub_v.value) + Number(add_tot));
                    tax_v.value = Number(sub_v.value) * Number(taxrate);
                    tot_v.value = Number(tax_v.value) + Number(sub_v.value);
                    tax_v.value = Number(tax_v.value).toFixed(2);
                    sub_v.value = Number(sub_v.value).toFixed(2);
                    tot_v.value = Number(tot_v.value).toFixed(2);
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send("itemid=" + itemID + "&amount=1");
        finish = 0;
        document.cookie = "finish=0; path=/";
    }
}
```

add.php

```
    <?
if ($_REQUEST['itemid'] && $_REQUEST['amount'] && $_COOKIE['finish'] != 1) {

    require 'requires/connect.php';
    require 'requires/function.php';


    $_REQUEST['itemid'] = protect($_REQUEST['itemid'],'2');
    $_REQUEST['amount'] = protect($_REQUEST['amount'],'2');

    $sql = "SELECT id, ws_price FROM items WHERE id = '$_REQUEST[itemid]'";
    $sql2 = query($sql);
    $sql3 = mysql_numrows($sql2);
    $add_item = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
    $add_item['ws_price'] = $add_item['ws_price'] * $_REQUEST['amount'];

    if ($sql3 > 0) {

            if (strlen($_COOKIE['ua_email']) > 0 && strlen($_COOKIE['ua_pass']) > 0) {

            $_COOKIE['ua_email'] = protect($_COOKIE['ua_email'],'1');
            $_COOKIE['ua_pass'] = protect($_COOKIE['ua_pass'],'1');

            $sql = "SELECT id, province FROM user_account WHERE email = '$_COOKIE[ua_email]' AND pass = '$_COOKIE[ua_pass]'";
            $sql2 = query($sql);
            $sql3 = mysql_numrows($sql2);

            if ($sql3 > 0) {

                $user = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);

                $sql = "SELECT orderid FROM orders WHERE userid = '$user[id]'";
                $sql2 = query($sql);
                $sql3 = mysql_numrows($sql2);

                if ($sql3 > 0) {
                    $sql4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
                    $order_id = $sql4['orderid'];
                } else {
                    $sql = "SELECT orderid FROM orders ORDER BY orderid DESC";
                    $sql2 = query($sql);
                    $sql3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
                    $order_id = $sql3['orderid'] + 1;
                }

                $sql = "SELECT id, amount FROM orders WHERE userid = '$user[id]' AND orderid = '$order_id' AND itemid = '$_REQUEST[itemid]'";
                $sql2 = query($sql);
                $sql3 = mysql_numrows($sql2);

                if ($sql3 > 0) {
                    $sql4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);

                    if (($sql4['amount'] + $_REQUEST['amount']) > 0) {
                        $sql = "UPDATE orders SET amount = amount + $_REQUEST[amount] WHERE id = '$sql4[id]'";
                        $sql2 = query($sql);
                        echo "$user[province]-$add_item[ws_price]";
                    }

                } else {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (orderid, itemid, userid, amount) VALUES ('$order_id', '$_REQUEST[itemid]', '$user[id]', '$_REQUEST[amount]')";
                $sql2 = query($sql);

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I've searched and cannot come up with a simple way of fixing this issue, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What I do in such cases: I disable (block) the clickable element once a click is detected. Then I have all time in the world to make the ajax request, store things, visualize results. And only then, after a successful completion, the element is enabled again. Disabling is typically done by removing the bound js handler and visualizing the disabled state by making the element gray or opac.

Comment: I changed the onClick for the anchor and src for the image right at the start of the function and changed them back at the end. This brought me no success. I have, however, fixed the issue. Having figured it out now I feel like a fool for not trying this sooner, but it was as simple as making the request synchronus rather than asynchronous. Asynchronous allows multiple instances to overlap, which was my entire issue - the script being triggered way too many times all at once. Making it synchronous has forced each request to finish before the next begins. Yay! Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt that is a _real_ solution. Whilst it is true, that that request has to be completed for that routine to continue there is no reason that no other request might be started at the same time. The question of synchronous or asynchronous is only relevant for the scope the request takes place in, but not for the global scope. Keep in mind that a js script is nothing running from start to end. But if you are content, all is fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this issue was as simple as making the request Synchronous rather than Asynchronous. With the request being synchronous now, it forces each request to finish before allowing another instance to begin, therefore the scripts cannot possibly be run faster now than they can update on the screen. Cheers!